# Boundedness, isolation (closedness) and relatively compactness of set in $c_0$.

Tags: functional-analysis

> It is required to check the set for boundedness, isolation (closedness) and relatively compactness: $S=\left\{x\in c_0:\exists f\in L_1[0,1]\;\|f\|\leq1,\;\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\;\;x(k)=\displaystyle\int\limits_{2^{-k}}^{2\cdot2^{-k}}f(t)dt\right\}.$

I have proved the boundedness of the set, but the rest fails. If there was a space $L_2$, then I would apply the Holder inequality to prove relative compactness. Also in $L_2$, we can use the weak convergence of a subsequence and prove closure. But in *this* case I do not know what to do. Help me please.

I think we need to give a counterexample, since the criterion of relative compactness in $c_0$ cannot be applied, due to the condition on the norm, and not on the module. But I can’t...

Comment: It seems that $x\in S$ iff $|x(k)|\le 2^{-k}$ for all $k$. If this is correct then it is not hard to show that $S$ is compact in the $\sup$ norm, and has no isolated points.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, thanks for your comment. It seems to me that way too, having examined a few specific examples. If the condition $|f(x)|\leq1$ a.e. were given, I would even understand how to prove it. But what if the condition is given only on the norm?

Comment: Right. $f$ could be $2^k$ on some $[k2^{-k}, 2k.2^{-k}]$ and $0$ elsewhere.  So for each $k$ there is an $x_k\in S$ such that $x_k(n)=0$ for $n \ne k,$ and $x_k(k)=1.$ Then $S$ is $not$ compact.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, thanks for the example. Can you advise something about isolation? Due to the condition on the norm, I do not know what to do here.

Comment: Given $x\in S$ and $f\in L^1$ as in the formula, there must be some $k$ such that the measure of $\{t\in J_k: f(x)\ne 0\}$ is not zero, where $J_k=[2^{-k},2.2^{-k}].$ So we can find some $g\in L^1$ with $\|g\|=1$, where g agrees with $f$ except on $J_k,$ and such that $\int_{J_k}g$ is arbitrarily close to, but not equal to, $\int_{J_k}f.$ This yields $y\in S$ with $y(n)=x(n)$ for $n\ne k$, and $|y(k)-x(k)|$ "small" but not $0.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, sorry, I don’t understand. I thought it was necessary to prove or disprove that if $x_n\in S$, and $x_n\to x_0$ (in sup norm),then $\exists f_0 \in L_1$ such that $\|f_0\|\leq1$ and $x_0(k)=\int\limits_{2^{-k}}^{2\cdot2^{-k}}f_0(t)dt$. Sorry again, but I don’t see this in your comment, maybe becouse i'm not so smart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks to @DanielWainfleet, for helping to justify the lack of relativity compactness. My proof of closure: enough to show that $S= M$, where $M=\left\{x\in c_0:\;\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty|x_k|\leq1\right\}$. Inclusion $S\subset M$ is obvious. The reverse inclusion is obtained if for each element of $M$ we consider the step function $f(t)=2^{k}x_k$ for $t\in[2^{-k},2\cdot2^{-k}]$. Now it remains only to prove the closure of M. But this is done simply by determining the closedness of the set, by estimating the partial sums of the limit sequence.